# Selecting a value from a drop-down option using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to select a value from a drop-down option. The html is as follows:

```
<span id="searchTypeFormElementsStd">

    <label for="numReturnSelect"></label>
    <select id="numReturnSelect" name="numReturnSelect">
        <option value="200"></option>
        <option value="250"></option>
        <option value="500"></option>
        <option selected="" value="200"></option>
        <option value="800"></option>
        <option value="15000"></option>
        <option value="85000"></option>
    </select>

</span
```

I tried as follows:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='numReturnSelect']/option[text()='15000']").click()
```

What is wrong with it? Please help me!

Comment: Perhaps you Need `@value`, not `text()`?  My xpath-foo is too weak to be sure.

Comment: Not sure in Python. But hope you have a Select Module as similar to Select class in Java

Comment: The following error occurred:\nInvalidSelectorError

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Adrian Ratnapala is right and also i would choose `id` over `name`, so you can try the following :

```
find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='numReturnSelect']/option[@value='15000']").click()
```

OR

```
find_element_by_css_selector("select#numReturnSelect > option[value='15000']").click()
```

OR

you can use [`select_by_value(value)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_value) :

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#numReturnSelect")).select_by_value(15000).click()
```

Click here for more info on [`Select`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html).

Comment: The first one worked, but I did not tried second one. Thanks! BTW what magic you did?

Comment: Hahaha its no magic, `option[text()='15000']` will check if any option tag has text `15000` but in your case `15000` was value attrubute. Anyways glad it Helped! i suggest you play around with the second and third as well, will help you explore selenium.

Comment: I hope you can answer my new question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525567/select-an-item-from-expandable-class-using-selenium-python

Comment: Its a webpage, just lookup by CSS

Answer (score 5):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Ie(".\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.get("https://test.com")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//input[@name='n_name']"""))
select.select_by_index(2)
select.select_by_visible_text('Visible Text')
select.select_by_value('value')
```

It will work fine