# Select an item from expandable class using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

For the following html:

```
<ul id="dataset-menu" class="treeview">

<li id="cat_01" class="expandable"></li>
<li id="cat_02" class="collapsable">
    <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea"></div>
    <span class="folder" title=""></span>
    <ul style="display: block;">
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <span class="collection">
                <div class="cell">
                    <input id="coll_5555" class="dataset_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dataset_checkbox" value="5555"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="cell"></div>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="last"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="cat_03" class="expandable"></li>
```

I have to select the item where the following occurs:

```
<input id="coll_5555" class="dataset_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dataset_checkbox" value="5555"></input>
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Whats problem are you facing here?

Comment: i could not expand the class to locate the item anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand first you have to click on li with id `cat_02` and then click on the `checkbox`.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#cat_02 div.collapsable-hitarea").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("coll_5555").click();
```

Comment: ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: when i run the first line code, no error but it does NOT expand the class.

Comment: the html code you've provided is from `ul` (`<ul id="dataset-menu" class="treeview">`), can you provide its parents html as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50102/discussion-between-amith-and-julie)