# Unable to select an element from a dropdown list with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, select, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

I need to select an element from a dropdown list using selenium webdriver in Python. For that I have checked helpful posts such as [Selecting a value from a drop-down option using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524621/selecting-a-value-from-a-drop-down-option-using-selenium-python) and 
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/how-do-i-work-with-dropdowns-in-selenium-webdriver?lq=1.

The element i am talking about is shown in the next block:

```
<div id="dayTab" style="height:20px" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
 <select class="input-small input-thin">
   <option value="2010">2010</option>
   <option value="2011">2011</option>
   <option value="2012">2012</option>
   <option value="2013">2013</option>
   <option value="2014">2014</option>
   <option value="2015">2015</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

I tried `Select()`:

```
yearselect = Select(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("select.input-small.input-thin"))
yearselect.select_by_value("2010")
```

Although it locates the element (which it does), i then get the following error which occurs for the second line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\elek2\workspace\webdriving\src\gotonch.py", line 119, in <module>
yearselect.select_by_value("2010")
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 79, in select_by_value
self._setSelected(opt)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 195, in _setSelected
option.click()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 74, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 453, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
(Session info: chrome=45.0.2454.101)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

I am not sure why this happens but i have also tried to use `Click()` instead in order to "open" the drop down list

```
yearselect =browser.find_element_by_css_selector("select.input-small.input-thin").click()
yearselect.select_by_value("2010")
```

and that the elements are visible but then I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\elek2\workspace\webdriving\src\gotonch.py", line 118, in <module>
yearselect = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("select.input-small.input-thin").click()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 74, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 453, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
(Session info: chrome=45.0.2454.101)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078   (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

Why is element still not visible if I am able to locate  the drop-down list and select it?

**EDIT**:

After [LINGS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392498/lings) comment I realised that there is *not only one* element with the css name that I 've used.

I am after the above block but there is another block referenced before that one where instead of `div id="dayTab"...` is  `div id="monthTab"...` which obviously is invisible. How can I refer to the tab that I want, there's no ID.

Comment: Do you know for sure if there is only one element on the page with css `select.input-small.input-thin` and that element is your element? You may be clicking on another select which has the same css and it is invisible.

Comment: @LINGS You are right, that's the problem, thanks. I will edit my OP as I am not sure how to pick the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was quite simple after all, I replaced the initial:

```
yearselect = Select(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("select.input-small.input-thin"))
yearselect.select_by_value("2010")
```

with this:

```
yearselect = Select(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#dayTab > select.input-small.input-thin"))
yearselect.select_by_value("2010")
```

It is only a matter of finding the correct CSS (or XPath). Chrome add-ons such as [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl) may help in this. Other tips on CSS selectors you may find in [here](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors). Glad in case I've helped other users avoid such annoying mistakes.