# Can't click to dropdown element. Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium, select

My task is to ckoose one of dropdown elements.

My HTML is:

```
<td>
<select name="subtract">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Да</option>
<option value="0">Нет</option>
</select>
</td>
```

My code is:

```
>>>selectbox = ff.find_element_by_name("subtract")
>>>print (selectbox.text)
Да
Нет
>>>print(Select(selectbox).options)
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x00000000037992E8>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0000000003799278>]
>>>print(Select(selectbox).select_by_index(0))
None
>>>print(Select(selectbox).select_by_value('0'))
None
>>>print(Select(selectbox).select_by_visible_text('Нет'))
None
```

So I really can't find where I am wrong?

Comment: 1.click(wait for the drop down to open ) 2.scroll to the element 3. click on the element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting a value from a drop-down option using selenium python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524621/selecting-a-value-from-a-drop-down-option-using-selenium-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about `Select`. But try this code:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='subtract']/option[@value='0']").click()
```

or this

```
find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='subtract']/option[@value='1']").click()
```

**EDIT:**
or try using [`Select`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) using xpath:

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='subtract']").select_by_value('0')
```

Comment: You should be using Select... it's built specifically to handle `SELECT` elements and `OPTIONS`.

Comment: @JeffC - Well, if you look at the question, OP did try to use `Select` but it didn't work. The code which OP used seems legit but it was still not selecting that element. Hence, I suggested to find the element and click on it. Anyways, updated the answer. Have a look.

Comment: He's using it wrong. All of the `select_by_*`s return void... so what is it supposed to print???

Comment: The `.click()` after `select_by_value()` should be removed. It's not needed since `select_by_value()` actually selects the value.

Comment: @JeffC - Well, OP did use `Select(selectbox).select_by_value('0')` but it didn't work for him.

Comment: @JeffC - Correction made to the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yep but he used `print(Select(selectbox).select_by_value('0'))` which returned `None`... but this statement returns `void` so I don't know whether he understood what he was doing and realized that it selected the option but printed `None` anyway. Hard to know at this point...